# Measure or model structure in geographical points and associated values

Tags: correlation

I have a list of 'scores' that are associated with locations (lat/lon). I would like to determine whether the score correlates somehow with the location. E.g. perhaps there are regions where the score is higher, or perhaps there is a linear relationship between 'lat' and score. Is there some way to test this? I'm looking for some kind of correlation-like measure of the structure, or even better, a way to model the structure.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how large is your area of interest, that is, if Earth can be assumed flat in your area or if we need to take in account that it's spherical. Some answers point to correlation between x and y (I assume lat/lon) and your scores, and that's fine for relatively small areas but it won't work if your data are distributed in the whole globe or even just at very different longitudes.

Comment: The locations cover an area of some 150x75 km. I'm not sure whether that can be assumed flat. In any case I don't think the lat/lon coordinates could be interpreted as regular x/y even if it was flat, because the units along the axes are not of equal length, right?

Comment: Yes, for most analysis converting lat/lon to an ortogonal x/y grid is good, and for a 150x75 km it can be done with only a minor distortion - it couldn't be done for the whole Earth. Anyway, for some analysis an x/y grid will give   (in small areas) the same results than lat/long: for example, a regression analysis of your score would give the same results using x/y or lat/long predictors; the change of units will just get included in parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most tests return a continuous measure of the strength of the relationship, and so it's easier to characterize how closely linked the variables are then it is to give a yes/no answer. (This is generally more useful, though; knowing that location is 80% predictive of score vs. 20% predictive of score is better than just knowing that it's predictive.)

Testing for correlation is easy--you can just run a [multiple correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correlation) test.

It's easy because correlation is specifically a *linear* relationship. You might be looking at the height of a symmetric smooth volcano, for example, where there is *not* a correlation between lat or lon and the height but the height could be predicted exactly given the lat and lon.

More helpful are measures of dependence, like [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_mutual_information), or nonlinear fitting methodologies, which often get called 'machine learning.'

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is with geostatistics (possibly using a glm) with spatial effect.

You can model your scores as a random variable with this shape: $$ Z(x,y) = \lambda S(x,y) + \epsilon $$

Where S(x,y) is a random process (the simplest with, binormal assuming stationary, finite variance and constant mean) .

You'll like to see if the variable Z(x,y) has some kind of spatial autocorrelation.

There are different ways to check this.

Check how the variance changes with respect to the distance (semivariogram).
Check also if it changes with respect to the orientation (anisotropy).

There are a lot of packages in R that can help you.

GSTAT is a classic and very useful.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gstat/vignettes/spatio-temporal-kriging.pdf

good luck!